# How can I play mp3 files stored in my Windows Phone 8.1 solution?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a number of mp3 files stored in my solution at the location

```
/Resources/mp3Files/
```

In Windows Phone 8 I was able to play these with the following:

```
var name = track.Item1;
var uri = new Uri("/Resources/mp3Files/sound.mp3", UriKind.Relative);

var song = Song.FromUri(name, uri);

FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
MediaPlayer.Play(song);
```

However, in Windows Phone 8.1 this doesn't work.

What do I need to do to play mp3 files I have stored in my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked:

```
// get folder app is installed to
var installFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

// get folders mp3 files are installed to.
var resourcesFolder = await installFolder.GetFolderAsync("Resources");
var mp3FilesFolder = await resourcesFolder.GetFolderAsync("mp3Files");

// open the mp3 file async
var audioFile = await mp3FilesFolder.GetFileAsync("sound.mp3");
var stream = await audioFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

// play dat funky music
MediaElement mediaplayer = new MediaElement();
mediaplayer.SetSource(stream, audioFile.ContentType);
mediaplayer.Play();
```

Comment: Do you have any reference or sample for music player ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use MediaElement in Windows 8.1: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnkenn/archive/2013/12/31/supporting-background-audio-in-your-windows-8-1-app.aspx

Playing Audio from a file stored in the Music folder

```
var audioFile = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync("/Resources/mp3Files/sound.mp3");

var stream = await audioFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

mediaplayer.SetSource(stream, audioFile.ContentType);
```

Take a look for a whole example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj841209.aspx

Comment: this looks promising, but it's giving me a `UnauthorizedAccessException`

Comment: Hmm. try to put mp3 files in other place maybe, for example in your Music Library

Comment: I figured that I need to give permission for the UnauthorizedAccessException but now it's another issue, a System.ArgumentException. I'll keep at on Monday as I'm finished now - woohoo, beer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how one used to open a file in WP8.0 embedded in solution with 'Build Action' 'Content':

```
Dim fs As IO.FileStream = IO.File.OpenRead("MyFolder/MyFile.txt")
```

And here is how it is done in WP8.1 Win-RT:

```
Dim fs As System.IO.Stream = Await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.OpenStreamForReadAsync("MyFolder\MyFile.txt")
```

Notice how "/" has changed to "\".